# What is causing this problem in flutter? Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate?

Tags: xcode, flutter

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                            8.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:

```
objc[19485]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both ?? (0x20ffb8188) and ?? (0x13047c2b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[19485]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both ?? (0x20ffb81d8) and ?? (0x13047c308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
** BUILD FAILED **
```

Xcode's output:

```
error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output
CompileC /Users/RuideWang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fxrieyfdpcpzjtcjlryrysiwwmvu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/geolocator.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/GeolocatorPlugin.o /Users/RuideWang/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator-7.0.3/ios/Classes/GeolocatorPlugin.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
/Users/RuideWang/Desktop/Programmieren/rift-1/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:28:1: error: expected '}' in class
^
/Users/RuideWang/Desktop/Programmieren/rift-1/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:6:45: note: to match this opening '{'
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
                                            ^
/Users/RuideWang/Desktop/Programmieren/rift-1/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:5:1: error: 'UIApplicationMain' attribute can only apply to one class in a module
@UIApplicationMain
^
/Users/RuideWang/Desktop/Programmieren/rift-1/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:17:1: error: 'UIApplicationMain' attribute can only apply to one class in a module
@UIApplicationMain
^
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Analyzing workspace
note: Constructing build description
note: Build preparation complete
note: Removed stale file '/Users/RuideWang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fxrieyfdpcpzjtcjlryrysiwwmvu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/geolocator/geolocator.framework'
note: Removed stale file '/Users/RuideWang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fxrieyfdpcpzjtcjlryrysiwwmvu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.framework'
note: Removed stale file '/Users/RuideWang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fxrieyfdpcpzjtcjlryrysiwwmvu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hexcolor/hexcolor.framework'
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: are you using any api in your code? is it http or https?

Comment: Hey, yes I am using the google maps package. just solved the problem, there was a problem in the AppDelegate.swift document